# I am trying to use the unofficial API for StockX, when trying to feed my login details i get an error

Tags: python

I am currently trying to play around with the unofficial stockx api which is found here:

https://pypi.org/project/stockx-py-sdk/

When i try passing in my login details in the below code i get the following error:

> File "stockxapi.py", line 11, in 
>       stockx.authenticate(email, password)   File "/Users/xxxxxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/stockxsdk/wrapper.py",
>   line 48, in authenticate
>       customer = response.json().get('Customer', None)   File "/Users/xxxxxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py",
>   line 897, in json
>       return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)   File "/Users/xxxxxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/json/**init**.py", line 354, in
>   loads
>       return _default_decoder.decode(s)   File "/Users/xxxxxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in
>   decode
>       obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())   File "/Users/xxxxxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in
>   raw_decode
>       raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char
>   0)

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt
import numpy
from stockxsdk import Stockx

stockx = Stockx()

email='xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com'
password='xxxxxxxxxxx'
stockx.authenticate(email, password)
```

I just want to be able to pass in my login details and have 'True' returned in the command line.

Comment: Tough to say without digging into the code itself.. but it looks like the JSON that the code is parsing might be malformed?

Answer (score 0):

Today I've been trying to play with the same unofficial API and just met the same issue. I figured that inside `stockx.authenticate(email, password)` authentication is failing due to HTTP 403 (Forbidden) response ending up in a JSONDecodeError... I assume this is due to change on stockx serverside to prevent scraping via automated tools but maybe this is avoidable by adding sufficient information to the HTTP request header.

```
In [17]: response = requests.post(endpoint, json=payload)                                                                                                                    

In [18]: response                                                                                                                                                            
Out[18]: <Response [403]>

Access to this page has been denied because we believe you are using automation tools to browse the website.
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that StockX closed their APIs. Therefore, when you call the authenticate function, the request returns a 403 code while the function is expecting a JSON string, and in turn, it throws a JSONDecodeError exception.